# Getting first element of embedded array in mongoDB using Node JS driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have the following document stored in a mongoDB collection 'people':

```
{ 
      _id: 489324,
     name: "Ryan Jones"
   skills: [ "fishing", "programming" ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve Ryan Jones's first skill in the array (skills[0]).

This seems like a dead simple operation but I can't seem to do it using the Node JS driver. I can retrieve just the skills array easily:

```
db.collection('people').findOne({ name:"Ryan Jones"},{ projection: { skills:1 }})
```

...but I don't want to transfer the whole array over the wire. I just want to get "fishing".

I have tried using slice and arrayElemAt within projection but I get a MongoError. How can I achieve this using the NodeJS driver? Does it require a more complex aggregation operation instead of findOne?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with aggregation , with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) something like this

```
db.collection('people').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "Ryan Jones"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      skills: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$skills",
          0
        ]
      },

    }
  }
])
```

See demo [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CyaGNB6MxxH)

Comment: Thanks, this aggregation also works and after timing operations vs the findOne method Valijon proposed there is no difference in speed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection('people').findOne({
  name: "Ryan Jones"
},
{
  skills: {
    $slice: 1
  }
})
```

[MongoTemplate with `.find`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bqEfm9REIsg)

Comment: I managed to get this to work by wrapping it in { projection : ... } which is needed for the NodeJS driver. However, the default behaviour is to then project the other fields in the document so I had to manually set them to not project, i.e._id:0, name:0