# Conditional $sort in aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I wanted conditional sort on price, There are two types of price in the database, so I am checking whether the `sellType` is `fixed price` or `bid`,

`if(sellType===fixed price)` then I want to fetch the normal price but,
`if(sellType===bid)` then I want to fetch the price from the object which is stored at 0th position in the array.

So I've tried to make aggregated query, sharing my code snippet

```
{
  $addFields: {
    sortedPrice: {
      $cond:  {
        if: {
          $eq: ["$itemDetail.sellType","fixed price"]
        },
        then: '$itemDetail.price',
        else:  '$itemDetail.bidInfo[0].price',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried all the possible solutions but not able to fetch the price from the `bidInfo` array. `bidInfo` is an array of objects but I want only the 0th position object (price to be very precise)

Comment: Try with `$arrayElemAt`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61425173/getting-first-element-of-embedded-array-in-mongodb-using-node-js-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `$arrayElemAt`,

```
 {
        $addFields: {
            sortedPrice: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ['$itemDetail.sellType', 'fixed price'],
                    },
                    then: '$itemDetail.price',
                    else: { $arrayElemAt: ['$itemDetail.bidInfo.price', 0] },
                },
            },
        },
    },
```